# Macbook air keeps disconnecting audio source

Tags: macbook-pro, headphones, airpods

I have a new Macbook Air (2019 version) with macOS Catalina. My issue is that it keeps disconnecting the audio output I'm using. This has been occurring ever since I bought the mac 3 weeks ago, rendering it useless to play music.

If I plug in my headset with minijack, I'll get to play music for about 1-5 minutes, before the Mac goes into some form of epilepsy mode, where I can observe in the audio settings that the audio output (in this case external headset) is removed and added very rapidly, sometimes naming the source "unknown", like every half second for about 2-3 minutes, before resuming to play music.

If I physically take out the mini jack during this epilepsy mode, the Mac will play music from the internal speakers, which is now named "unknown". During this time I'm not able to change the volume, having to quit iTunes/Spotify to make the music stop.

This occurs suddenly and without any obvious triggers. Its been happening 2 times while writing this post. It seems to happens regardless of external monitors, what programs are running, and happens on 2 different headsets with minijack and even with my bluetooth connected Airpods.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps that was why it was sold by the previous owner?

Comment: @SteveChambers it is new, the company I work for bought it.

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried everything, seems like the only way of fixing it for me now is to restart. I thought it could be a dongle, have used official Apple one, happens after a couple of days. Tried to kill and restart the coreaudio, nothing except restart works.

Comment: Also have exactly the same issue. Glad to see i'm not the only one? Is this officially registered with apple anywhere? (Am also on macbook air and catalina)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening to me, you need to unplug the jack and put it back in.